# Are pinnable taskpanes / the SupportsPinning element supported in Office 2019 (the one time purchase, non-Office 365 version)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In the documentation for pinnable taskpanes I'm seeing one page say it's supported for Office 365 subscribers with Office 2016 or higher, implying the one time purchase editions are not supported, while another page says it's supported by Office 2016 (a specific version) and higher.

I have a client who does not subscribe to Office 365 asking if they will be able to pin the taskpane if they upgrade to Office 2019. Unfortunately I don't have a copy of Office 2019 to test for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are supported in Office 2019 Enterprise.

For more context please refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane

You can find this extract from the above URL : Pinnable task panes are currently available to Office 365 subscribers using Outlook 2016 or later on Windows (build 7668.2000 or later for users in the Current or Office Insider Channels, build 7900.xxxx or later for users in Deferred channels), Outlook 2016 or later on Mac (version 16.13.503 or later), and Outlook on the web.